# Replacing one character with two (\n by \r\n ) replaces also one of the replacing characters

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert large number of files to a common line endings with this script. The script is called in git-shell using for loop.

After running all line endings have only CR as line ending. I suppose because replace(contents, '\n', '\r\n' ) replaces also \n after \r. Is there a may to prevent it? Should I replace linewise?

```
import sys
import string
import os.path

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        continue
    contents = open(file, 'rb').read()
    cont1 = string.replace(contents, '\n', '\r\n' )
    open(file, 'wb').write(cont1)
```

Comment: You know that git has this function built-in? No need for a script: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: I use git shell only as bash on windows. The sources are manager in SVN in the project. I wanted only to convert XML-files, because the parser seems to break, when mixed line endings occure. Other files should remain as is.

Comment: Just saying that `string.replace()` is not available on python3.x. So this is python2-only code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code literally copy-paste and it works just fine on python2.7:

```
bash$ cat file1
one
two

bash$ file file1
file1: ASCII text

bash$ hd file1
00000000  6f 6e 65 0a 74 77 6f 0a                           |one.two.|
00000008

bash$ python2 lineend.py file1

bash$ hd file1
00000000  6f 6e 65 0d 0a 74 77 6f  0d 0a                    |one..two..|
0000000a

bash$ file file1
file1: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Note however that your are opening the same file twice: once for reading and once for writing. Probably won't cause problems in this exact case, but generally that is not good practice.

```
import sys
import string
import os.path

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        continue
    f = open(file, 'rb')
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()
    cont1 = string.replace(contents, '\n', '\r\n' )
    open(file, 'wb').write(cont1)
```

Comment: OK, thank you! You are right. The files contained mixed line endings. The  \r-s came not from replacement string but from some spread \r\n among unix-enidngs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.sub` to perform a regex substitution.

Instead of this line:

```
cont1 = string.replace(contents, '\n', '\r\n' )
```

You would use the following line (don't forget to `import re`):

```
cont1 = re.sub(r'([^\r])\n', r'\g<1>\r\n', contents)
```

Update:

`r'([^\r])\n'` will not match a newline at the beginning of the file. Using `r'([^\r])?\n'` instead should do the job.